# Index Numpy tensor without having to reshape

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have a tensor with the shape `(5,48,15)`. How can I access an element along the 0th axis and still maintain 3 dimensions without needing to reshape. For example:

```
x.shape                    # this is (5,48,15) 
m = x[0,:,:] 
m.shape                     # This is  (48,15)
m_new = m.reshape(1,48,15) 
m_new.shape                 # This is now (1,48,15)
```

Is this possible without needing to reshape?

Comment: What is `x`? Can you add a sample input and expected output to your question? If you want to access to 0th axis of your array what you didn't just do `m[0,:,:]`?

Comment: I want to axis m[0,:,:] but maintain a shape of (1,48,15), accessing m[0,:,:] is (48,15). Just wondering if there is a method to preserve dimensions when indexing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you index an axis with a single integer, as with `x[0, :, :]`, the dimensionality of the returned array drops by one.

To keep three dimensions, you can either...

- insert a new axis at the same time as indexing:

  ```
  >>> x[None, 0, :, :].shape
  (1, 48, 15)
  ```
- or use slicing:

  ```
  >>> x[:1, :, :].shape
  (1, 48, 15)
  ```
- or use fancy indexing:

  ```
  >>> x[[0], :, :].shape
  (1, 48, 15)
  ```

Comment: Perfect, the slice syntax is what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The selection index needs to be a slice or list (or array):

```
m = x[[0],:,:]
m = x[:1,:,:]
m = x[0:1,:,:]
```